# Scrollable Table leaves residual border

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm not sure if this is a CSS/tailwind bug or if it is something I'm doing wrong, but I observed this behavior while using Tailwind.
When scrolling across the table, the container seems to be leaving a border behind at the point where the container ends before scrolling.

[image: Border]

This happens on Chrome and Firefox.

Reproduction:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/Af6gaRCIk6?size=326x720

Comment: Issue seems to be coming from this element: `<div class="shadow rounded-md w-full h-full">`. Do you even need the `<div />` there?

Comment: @juliomalves it is. It's width is causing the problem. The 2 classes needs to be moved to table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning `.shadow` and `.rounded-md` to wrong element. What you're seeing is the border of the div.

This was your code.

```
<div class="shadow rounded-md h-full">
  <table class="min-w-max sm:min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200 text-sm p-4 h-full">
```

I removed the those classes from parent div and added it to table.

```
<div class="h-full">
   <table class="shadow rounded-md min-w-max sm:min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200 text-sm p-4 h-full">
```

Here's the updated fiddle https://play.tailwindcss.com/VVzJe0OSIy?size=326x720

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The issue is the divs with shadows are part of a `card` react component. I probably should have mentioned this in the post but I  didn't think it would matter too much. The importance  of this is i'm not sure I can move the shadows  without ruining the overall aesthetic of the card component. I'll play around tomorrow  and see what can be done. Briefly looking at your fiddle, I can see what you mean  about the width of  the  inner div. Thanks again for the response.